# Resolving the types of functions in external modules

Tags: compiler-construction, module, programming-languages, static-typing

Suppose we have an imaginary statically typed programming language - let's call it *SL*. Each SL file corresponds to a *module* - SL's logical grouping of related functions into namespaces.

Calls to functions in the current module are easily checked: A compiler pass discovers all declared functions and stores their signatures. We can later verify any such calls by comparing the argument types to the types of the formal arguments in the signature.

However, handling calls to functions in *other* modules seems a bit more involved. In particular, assuming the compiler can locate the source/object code corresponding to the name of an imported module, how does it extract the type information? Does it:

- Scan and parse the imported module's source code until it finds the function declaration?
- Read some kind of metadata from the object file?
- Encode the function return type and parameter types in the symbol name and read the symbol table during compile time?
- Find metadata elsewhere?

I'm curious as to what approach compilers for modern languages like Haskell, D and Go take.

---

Edit: I'm aware that C and C++ solve this problem using header files. I am not interested that approach. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve any parsing at all.

Comment: Are you looking for the functional equivalent of [#import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pragma? Or the equivalent of the [midl compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?.

Comment: Nothing so specialized - I'm just generally curious about how one can go about determining the types of external functions during compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that this kind of type resolution is a property of the compiler, not the language as such.  Different implementations of C/C++ actually provide different features along these lines -- e.g., Microsoft's "precompiled headers" option.

Haskell's GHC compiler handles this by generating interface files (with ".hi" suffixes) that contain the necessary type information.  I suppose this qualifies as "find the metadata elsewhere".

Comment: Exactly the kind of information I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you need a header file for c/c++ to include a static library or a dll. For dlls you can figure out functions by inspecting the dll only. So it means the dll file stores the names of functions, return values and parameter types. There are some tools that generates this declarations.

Actually you give the solution for your question. All the methods are used depending on situation.

> Read some kind of metadata from the object file?

For dynamic libraries like dlls you can dynamicly query object code and call it via function pointers. for go http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsDLLs
so yes. .net languages like c#, vb uses this a lot.

> Find metadata elsewhere?

For C/C++ you need a header file for definitions if static libraries are used. I can not give example for the languages you say.

> Scan and parse the imported module's source code until it finds the function declaration?

If you have the code it is the obvious way of doing just like the other code you have.

I dont thinks this is different for Go, D or Haskell than C/C++.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that I'm well aware of how C and C++ solve this problem. (Post edited) What I'm after is an explanation of how languages like Go discover the types of functions exported by other modules/packages during *compile time*, i.e., without leaving it to the linker.

Comment: Types of functions are should be decided at compile time for statically typed languages. even for dll's you should have the declaration to compile(though giving wrong declaration is possible which results chaotic runtime problems)

Comment: why are you seperating C++ from other languages. because of not being "modern"?

Comment: Because it doesn't really have modules in the same sense that Haskell does, for example.